# @xxx.edu email verification method for ios mobile application

Tags: ios, swift3

I am writing a new mobile application for iOS that is @xxx.edu specific. I am stuck when it comes to verifying the email. My goal is that once the email is verified, it sends a 4 digit code in the email that the person can input in the mobile app to get their account verified.

Comment: Sounds good. What exactly is your question?

Comment: To verify an email adddress send it an email?  What is the actual problem?

Comment: I apologize for not clarifying it. The problem is that to verify that the email entered by the user is an actual @xxx.edu email and to send the 4 digit code to that email entered by the user. A lot of my research tells me to use Parse.com and some say Firebase, but not sure where to begin or how to begin. Just need to be pointed at the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [NSRegularExpression](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsregularexpression) check at the client side.
But you should also do a server side check to verify that the user didn't tamper with the data after it was sendt.

Example code:

```
func isValidEmail(email:String) -> Bool {
let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[\\bedu\\b]{2,}"

let emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)
return emailTest.evaluate(with: email)
}

isValidEmail(email: "student@stud.edu")    //true
isValidEmail(email: "student@stud.com")    //false
```

Edit:
Firebase is a great and easy tool if you need a backend to store your data. I haven't used parse.com, but I think Firebase is easier for a beginner. Also if you want to send emails to the user, firebase can do that for you.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas off the top.

1. **Verify through verification link**

   This is pretty much what you're already doing. Once email is entered, you send a one-time 24-hour expiring verification link. Two possible scenarios I can think of. First, if email exists then you simply await for the user to click on the verification link. If email doesn't exist, then the verification email fails altogether hence you know its a fake email.

   ***UPDATE 12/2/2016***

   I would recommend you use [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) for your backend because of its large community which will come in handy when trying to resolve an issue. Plus it offers a bunch of services and its growing rapidly.

   I made a [Github](https://github.com/eshirima/StackOverFlowHelpII) project that demonstrates how to use Firebase to tackle your issue. I advice you run the program first and try it out. There's ample amount of documentation so as you won't get lost or feel overwhelmed. Along with this, I'd recommend you watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8sRUhzgJhcY) video demonstrating how to perform email & password login with Firebase.
2. **In-app email verification**

   Since the emails are of specific university domains, one way you could do is ask the universities for any API access for email verification purposes only because chances are they won't freely provide you with their email databases.

   The other option is using a third party email verification such as [emailhippo](https://www.emailhippo.com/en-US/verify-email-address/api/a).

*Two Cents: Just stick with the old school way of sending a one time verification link. Email verification is an issue faced by even global companies because there are just too many scenarios to handle e.g. What if the user used the [10 minute mail service](https://10minutemail.net/)? What if the email is actually valid but your verification system returned not valid because of some security features? etc*

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the help!

Comment: how would you suggest going about the first method.

Comment: What backend service are you using? If none would you be open to exploring other available backend services?

Comment: currently i am using none. but yeah i am open to suggestions.

Comment: so im leaning towards Microsoft Azure for backend support in terms of storing data (log in credentials, and more) for my mobile app.

Comment: @D.Patel I would recommend you use Firebase. Check my updated answer. Please upvote and mark as answer if it resolves your issue. Happy coding, cheers mate :)